# Git merge issue

Tags: xcode, git, merge

I am using a local repository (which doesn't work at all like the local repository seemed to work in the Xcode demo I watched on Lynda.com). The only way I can get it to work is to create another copy of my project directory and then point to that as a working directory within Organizer. Ok... that's fine, though it wasn't supposed to work like that according to the demo which I followed step-by-step.

Now my current issue is that when I wanted to check something on my production branch while I was working on another that had some uncommitted changes, I switched branches and it *merged all the files!!!* Seriously... wtf. So now my production project is completely screwed and it won't let me switch back to the other branch either until I fix the merge conflict.

So my question is: is this regular git behaviour, or is my repository system screwy? If it is indeed regular behaviour, you'd think there'd be at least a warning dialogue telling you that you have uncommitted changes and that it's going to merge your branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git generally doesn't let you switch branches with uncommited changes. You either have to commit them or stash them before moving branches.

Look up git-stash to see how that works.

I've never used git through Xcode, so I have a feeling it's doing something strange behind the scenes because it is not normal for this to happen. It will complain about a dirty work tree and tell you to stash before switching branches.

Comment: Thanks -- so I guess I'll just have to remember to commit everything first before I switch branches. Frankly I think something is wacky with my git implementation within Xcode... the guy on Lynda didn't have to create a working copy for a local repository and it seemed to work fine for him.

Comment: Oh great... so I managed to resolve the conflicts and get my working production branch working again but now my main story board refuses to commit. Awesome.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you have repo A and then you cloned that into repo B. Then you did work in B and are trying to push it to A? If that's the case, then A cannot have the branch checked out that you are trying to push. You either need to create a dummy branch and have that checked out on A, or you need to make A a bare repo.

Comment: I got the problem solved... the file was indicating erroneously that it had uncommitted changes. So I simply added a comment and built the project and then it would allow me to commit. There is definitely something weird with my git.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Git that well. I mainly use Mercurial. So I can't give you a better answer than this:

You might want to look at the [Pro Git](http://progit.org/book/) book. Also, familiarize yourself with Git on the command line before you start working with it via Xcode. A solid understanding of the actual Git tools will help you understand the way the IDE interface works.